# Same page with 2 urls .htaccess no redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a page where i am listing all my products. But i want the same page on different url also. So the both urls should open same page with any redirect.

Original URL is: `http://example.com/product/all-products`
New URL with same content should be `http://example.com/all-products`

How can i do that with .htaccess?

Comment: what is your original url means to which you are redirecting?

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar Original url means i have a page running where all of my products are listed. i just want to create another url to access the same page without any redirect

Answer (score 0):

Try the below rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ product/$1 [L]
```

Comment: what will hthe code to redirect to abc.com/product/products

Comment: you _could_ try to do something yourself @mohit. This is a Q&A site, not a free developers work site

Comment: actually that is what i mean with original url `abc.com/product/products` is rewrite to which url you understand me like `product.php?name=products`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in **/root.htaccess** :

```
RewriteEngine on
#1 redirect browser url from "/product/foobar" to "/foobar"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product/(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R,NE]
#2 if "/foobar" exists as a file or dir in product folder
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/product/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/product/$1 -d
#3 then rewrite "/foobar" to "/product/foobar"
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /product/$1 [L]
```

If the example above fails, you could try the following

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product/(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /product/$1 [L]
```